# NSData myView Leak

Tags: iphone

For my long search about nsdata there is some leaks still there .......................When we get value of nsdata from the website url leaks occur.... That website url contains html page means there is no leak in this code ....Else it contains xml page means it gives memory leak..

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/startpage"];
NSData *data ;
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];
NSData *data ;
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I can test with this url ... Is there any reason ?

```
My leaked object 
GeneralBlock-1536(1.50kb)
NSCFString - (144 Bytes)
NSURL -(32 Bytes)
```

I test with instrument in simulator and device also... can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code there's isn't any leaks coming from you, so it's probably leaks from other places, or in fact from Apple's code.

You can check the call tree in instruments to see where the leak actually happens.